# Manipulating items in a list, from a string then turning it back to a string

Tags: python, string, list, data-manipulation, suffix

I applied to a data engineer job not too long ago, I got a Python question that didn’t meet all the edge cases and it had been haunting me since, I used `.endswith()` at that time and I feel like that’s what failed in my code

I have been trying to recode it and here is what I have so far:

```
x = 'cars that ran up and opened a 
tattooaged car dealership educated'
# create a program to remove 'ed' from 
# any word that ends with ed but not 
# the word 'opened'
# also, every word must be less than 
# 8 letters long

suffix= 'ed'

def check_ed_lt8(x):
    x_list=x.split(" ")
    for index,var in enumerate(x_list):
        if suffix in var != 'opened':
            new_word = var[:-len(suffix)].strip('suffix')
            x_list[index] = new_word
        elif len(var) >= 8:
            shorter_word = var[:8]
            x_list[index] = shorter_word
    return(' '.join(x_list))

print(check_ed_lt8(x))
```

I get the desired output:

```
cars that ran up and opened a tatooag car dealersh educat
```

But the technical question had examples before it, like some words ending in ‘ly’ and I started wondering if I maybe just had to loop through a list of suffixes, and that’s why I don’t pass the edge cases so I modified my code but now, every time I add on to the list, I lose manipulation over one of the last items in the list

```
suffixes = ['ed', 'an']
def check_ed_lt8(x):
    x_list=x.split(" ")
    for index,var in enumerate(x_list):
        for suffix in suffixes:
            if suffix in var != 'opened':
                new_word = var[:-len(suffix)].strip('suffix')
                x_list[index] = new_word
            elif len(var) >= 8:
                shorter_word = var[:8]
                x_list[index] = shorter_word
    return(' '.join(x_list))

print(check_ed_lt8(x))
```

Returns:

```
cars that r up a opened a tattoag car dealersh educated
```

In this return, I lost manipulation over the last item AND I didn’t mean for “and” to lose “nd”. I know it lost it because of a combination of “d” and “n” from each prefix but I don’t know why

I lose more manipulation over the last few items the more items I place inside of the prefixes, for example if I add “ars” to the prefixes the outcome becomes:

```
c that r up a opened a tattoag car dealership educated
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first example doesn't seem to make sense syntactically. Note the messed up syntax highlighting.

Comment: I fixed what I could, how do I multi line comment here? Is it html?

Comment: `if suffix in var != 'opened':` What is this supposed to do? Looks like this is actually valid comparison chaining, but _please_ don't do this.

Comment: @tobias_k okay, I’ll take your advice and research it, thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using re.sub for removing the ed at the end. Here is a one-liner:

```
import re
x = 'cars that ran up and opened a tattoo aged car dealership educated'
y = ' '.join([w if w == "opened" else re.sub(r'ed$', '', w)[:8] for w in x.split(' ')])
```

If you want to remove multiple suffixes, extend your regexp accordingly:

```
y = ' '.join([w if w == "opened" else re.sub(r'(ed|an)$', '', w)[:8] for w in x.split(' ')])
```

Of course you can also build the regexp based on a list of suffixes:

```
suffixes = ['ed','an']
pattern = re.compile('('+'|'.join(suffixes)+')$')
y = ' '.join([w if w == "opened" else pattern.sub('', w)[:8] for w in x.split(' ')])
```

Comment: I honestly need more exposure to regx, thanks for the feedback! I’ll be trying this out later today!

Comment: Wow! This worked like a charm! I have a lot to learn, thanks again!